# Calculating vector to intercept a target with acceleration and drag

Tags: c#, game-physics

I'm trying to build a 4x space game with some invented physics to keep overall speed down and penalize making just bigger and bigger ships. Because of that I have added a drag component to movement.

But I can't figure out how to calculate interception vectors for spaceship and missile movement when both spaceship and target will be moving and accelerating and being slowed down by my custom-made drag. Changing the direction to apply acceleration is going to be instant.

Being a novice programmer with lacking maths skills I can't figure this out, nor find an applicable solution with google.

Here is my movement code:

```
// Vector calculations for the movement.
double moveX = ((moveSpeed - (CalculateDrag(moveSpeed, owner.Size, owner.Mass) * timeToProcess)) * Math.Cos(moveHeading)) * timeToProcess;
double moveY = ((moveSpeed - (CalculateDrag(moveSpeed, owner.Size, owner.Mass) * timeToProcess)) * Math.Sin(moveHeading)) * timeToProcess;

// Vector calculations for acceleration.
double accX = ((accSpeed - (CalculateDrag(accSpeed, owner.Size, owner.Mass) * timeToProcess) / 2) * Math.Cos(accHeading) * timeToProcess) * timeToProcess;
double accY = ((accSpeed - (CalculateDrag(accSpeed, owner.Size, owner.Mass) * timeToProcess) / 2) * Math.Sin(accHeading) * timeToProcess) * timeToProcess;

// Add the vectors.
double xVelocity = moveX + accX;
double yVelocity = moveY + accY;

// Get the new vector.
owner.Location.Heading = Math.Atan2(yVelocity, xVelocity);
owner.Location.Speed = (Math.Sqrt((xVelocity * xVelocity) + (yVelocity * yVelocity)) / timeToProcess);

// If the speed is really low, set it to 0.
if (owner.Location.Speed < 0.005)
{
    owner.Location.Speed = 0;
}

// Update the position.
owner.Location.X += xVelocity;
owner.Location.Y += yVelocity;
```

And here is the CalculateDrag method:

```
// Do the drag value calculations.
var drag = ((DragConst * (velocity) * (Math.Pow(size, DragExp))) / 1000000) / (mass);

return drag;
```

Comment: I assume your missiles don't track the target but instead travel in a straight line at constant speed? If the target is decelerating under drag (i.e. velocity decaying exponentially), you will need a numerical method to solve for the intersection time and direction; the tricky bit is dealing with edge cases.

Comment: No, missiles will be able to track the target and change their heading in flight. They will also be accelerating and be affected by drag, just like the space ship. So I guess I won't need a perfect initial solution, just something to send them in the correct direction. I'm also planning to use the same algorithm for all direction finding, spaceships rendezvousing with each other for instance. I guess I'll need a similar one for intercepting planets as they have their own movement rules.

Comment: FYI - You remove a lot of headaches if you actually define a vector structure instead of trying to keep track of individual components of vectors.